# How do I make my div with six different pictures expand outwards when clicking it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying this with a bunch of different jQuerys, but with slim to none success. I'm very new to this and trying to learn as much as I can.

This is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ogejrbup/ How can I make this work?

HTML

```
<div id="prototype">
<img style="height: 100px; width: 100px; position: absolute;"src="http://i.imgur.com/MEbxzVL.png" alt="menu1">

<img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;position: absolute;" src="http://i.imgur.com/TMZ4hXu.png" alt="menu2">

<img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;position: absolute;" src="http://i.imgur.com/VeJ6BR2.png" alt="menu3">

<img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;position: absolute;" src="http://i.imgur.com/aIYy0qr.png" alt="menu4">

<img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;position: absolute;" src="http://i.imgur.com/QO0Z8TE.png" alt="menu5">

<img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;position: absolute;" src="http://i.imgur.com/uGopItw.png" alt="menu6">
</div>

</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
/// background-image: url("wallpaper.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}

#prototype { 
position: absolute;
top: 45%;
left: 47.5%;
}
```

jQuery

```
$("#prototype").click(function() {
   $(this).attr('width', '400');
    $(this).attr('height', '300');
});
```

Comment: what is the point of the slashes in the css

Answer (score -1, accepted):

or using javascript this changes style on all images in the prototype div (you can also use it to change class for each)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function expand() {
        var imgs = prototype.getElementsByTagName("img");
        for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
            imgs[i].style.width = "400px";
            imgs[i].style.height = "300px";
        }
    }
</script>

<div id="prototype" onclick="expand();">
    <img style="height: 100px; width: 100px; position: absolute;" src="http://i.imgur.com/MEbxzVL.png" alt="menu1">

    <img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;position: absolute;" src="http://i.imgur.com/TMZ4hXu.png" alt="menu2">

    <img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;position: absolute;" src="http://i.imgur.com/VeJ6BR2.png" alt="menu3">

    <img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;position: absolute;" src="http://i.imgur.com/aIYy0qr.png" alt="menu4">

    <img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;position: absolute;" src="http://i.imgur.com/QO0Z8TE.png" alt="menu5">

    <img style="height: 100px; width: 100px;position: absolute;" src="http://i.imgur.com/uGopItw.png" alt="menu6">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest cropping the wedges to visible area and positioning those. It's much easier than trying to figure out the wedge offsets in the circle. Here's an example and please excuse the long javascript it's mostly for making the wedges.  Look at the css that positions them and the click function that toggles the class.  With that you can position any way you like

```js
var to_rad = Math.PI / 180;
var deg = 360 / 6;
var rad = deg * to_rad;

function wedge() {
  var c = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  c.canvas.width = c.canvas.height = 100;
  c.beginPath();
  c.fillStyle = "black", c.strokeStyle = "red", c.lineWidth = 2;

  c.translate(50, 50);
  c.rotate((-90 * to_rad) - rad);
  c.translate(-50, -50);
  c.moveTo(50, 50);
  c.arc(50, 50, 46, 0, rad);
  c.lineTo(50, 50);
  c.fill();
  c.stroke();
  return c.canvas;

}

function shape() {
  var c = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  c.canvas.width = c.canvas.height = 100;
  c.beginPath();
  c.fillStyle = "black", c.strokeStyle = "red", c.lineWidth = 2;


  function line(a, b, x, y) {
    c.moveTo(a, b);
    c.lineTo(x, y);
  }

  function rot(deg) {
    var to_rad = Math.PI / 180;
    var x = Math.floor(c.canvas.width / 2);
    var y = Math.floor(c.canvas.height / 2);
    c.translate(x, y);
    c.rotate(deg * to_rad);
    c.translate(-x, -y);
  }

  function rline(deg, a, b, x, y) {
    rot(deg);
    line(a, b, x, y);
  }

  c.moveTo(100, 50);
  c.arc(50, 50, 48, 0, to_rad * 360);
  c.fill();

  line(50, 0, 50, 100);
  c.moveTo(75, 50);
  c.arc(50, 50, 25, 0, 360 * to_rad);

  rline(deg * 2 - 90, 50, 50, 98, 50);
  rline(deg * 2, 50, 50, 98, 50);
  rline(deg, 75, 50, 98, 50);
  rline(deg * 2, 75, 50, 98, 50);

  c.stroke();

  return c.canvas;
}

function makeShapes() {

  var circ = shape();
  var x = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  var y = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  x.canvas.width = x.canvas.height = 100;
  y.canvas.width = y.canvas.height = 50;

  var w = wedge();
  var mask = [
    [50, 50],
    [0, 50],
    [0, 25],
    [0, 0],
    [50, 0],
    [50, 25]
  ];

  var items = [
    [0, 0],
    [-50, 0],
    [-50, -25],
    [-50, -50],
    [0, -50],
    [0, -25]
  ];

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var s = items[i];
    var k = mask[i];

    x.save();
    x.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    x.translate(k[0], k[1]);
    x.rotate(rad * i);
    x.translate(-50, -50);
    x.drawImage(w, 0, 0);
    x.restore();
    y.clearRect(0, 0, 50, 50)
    y.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    y.drawImage(x.canvas, 0, 0);
    y.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
    y.drawImage(circ, s[0], s[1]);
    var m = $('#prototype .m' + (i + 1));
    m.attr('style', "width: 50px; height: 50px");
    m.attr('src', y.canvas.toDataURL());
  }
}

makeShapes();

$("#prototype").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('pro-on');
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #222222;
}
.pro-wrap {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.pro-on {
  background-color: transparent !Important;
}
.pro-on .pro-wrap {
  top: 100px !important;
  background-color: #660066;
}
.pro,
.pro * {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.pro {
  background-color: #333333;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
}
.pro img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.pro-on img:hover {
  outline: 2px solid white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.pro .m2 {
  left: 50px;
}
.pro .m3 {
  left: 50px;
  top: 25px;
}
.pro .m4 {
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}
.pro .m5 {
  left: 0px;
  top: 50px;
}
.pro .m6 {
  left: 0px;
  top: 25px;
}
.pro-on {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.pro-on .m1 {
  left: -100px;
  top: -100px;
}
.pro-on .m2 {
  left: 150px;
  top: -100px;
}
.pro-on .m3 {
  left: 150px;
  top: 25px;
}
.pro-on .m4 {
  left: 150px;
  top: 150px;
}
.pro-on .m5 {
  left: -100px;
  top: 150px;
}
.pro-on .m6 {
  left: -100px;
  top: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id="prototype" class='pro'>
    <div class="pro-wrap">
      <img class="m1" alt="menu1">
      <img class="m2" alt="menu2">
      <img class="m3" alt="menu3">
      <img class="m4" alt="menu4">
      <img class="m5" alt="menu5">
      <img class="m6" alt="menu6">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Holy cow you really put a lot of effort into this, thank you so much! I'll study this code to try and understand what it means, because right now it looks like chinese. You're the best, and again, thank you so much @wolfhammer.

Comment: @GöranKempe your welcome and it's not as hard as it looks.  It's mostly drawing routines because I couldn't edit your image. All you need to do is edit your images to remove the empty areas leaving just the wedges.  Look at the bottom of the js for the click event. It toggles the pro-on class. Now look at the css and that's where the shapes are moved around.  You can go a lot further and add transitions to animate opening and closing the circle.

Comment: @GöranKempe okay now it's getting a tiny bit more complicated. I added the css transition and found that we needed a wrapper to make things smoother. There still seems to be a little flubbing with the movement.  I was interested to see what it would look like and it's kind of cool.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you have to call the jQuery CDN from your fiddle in order for jQuery to work.

Now, if what you want is to expand the container, then adding a class to your css and then adding that class to your container on click will work.

```
#prototype.expanded {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

$("#prototype").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('expanded');
});
```

If you want your images to expand with the container, then this will not work. Since they have specific heights.

You can see the working fiddle here:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ogejrbup/2/)

Comment: How would I go by if I wanted the images to expand with the container? Because that's what I originally wanted, sorry if that wasn't clear. Thank you for the fiddle tip as well!

Comment: or you could use `$(#prototype').children('img').css({...});` http://jsfiddle.net/t4d2d4oL/

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb +1 For a cleaner answer than the accepted one.